# Autovacuum is holding the ShareUpdateExclusiveLock for hours

Tags: postgresql, autovacuum

On one of my Postgres server autovacuum worker is holding ShareUpdateExclusiveLock for hours. At the same time, one of the application programs is trying to detach a partition from the table.

The application which is trying to detach the partition has acquired AccessExclusiveLock on the parent table and waiting to acquire ShareUpdateExclusiveLock on the partition to be detached, which blocks all select/insert operations on the table.

The data in the table is written by only one writer, no delete or update operation is performed.

The issue has triggered twice and the system became usable only after killing the process from the shell.

As per Postgres document if there is a conflict autovacuum worker will be interrupted. In which exceptional case this interruption may not work?

Postgres version is 12.11 and is using Patroni for clustering.

Comment: You referenced the docs.  Did you see [this part](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM): "However, if the autovacuum is running to prevent transaction ID wraparound (i.e., the autovacuum query name in the pg_stat_activity view ends with (to prevent wraparound)), the autovacuum is not automatically interrupted."?

Answer (score 0):

As Jeff commented, this is most likely an anti-wraparound autovacuum process, because other autovacuum processes would not block your SQL statements for more than a second. If you kill that autovacuum run, it will only come back, because it has an important job to do. If you had the nerve to keep killing that process, you would eventually get into worse trouble than you have now.

The solution is to let the autovacuum process run to completion. If that takes too long, see that `autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay` is set low enough for this table and that you set `maintenance_work_mem` high enough for good autovacuum performance.

Perhaps you got into this quandary by constantly attaching and detaching partitions, so that autovacuum could never complete its job. In that case, rethink your application design.

Comment: Attaching a partition happens only once a week and we detach the oldest partition only when we run out of disk space. autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay is 20ms, maintenance_work_mem is 100 MB and autovacuum_max_workers is 3. What's optimum value for these parameters?

Comment: 20ms delay makes autovacuum very slow. You should enable `log_autovacuum_min_duration` and see how long autovacuum takes.

Comment: This is an insert-only table, no update or deletion takes place. Could this be the reason for the slowness?